# Migration changes show in Schema file but not in the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For Rails 3.2 I have written this migration to rename the column name as seen in the migration

```
class RenameKpiColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
   rename_column(:key_performance_intervals, :kpi_id, :key_performance_interval_id)
 end
end
```

And then I said `bundle exec rails db:migrate`

If I go to Schema.rb I see this for that table, so looks likes it picked the new column name from Migration:

```
  create_table "key_performance_intervals", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "key_performance_interval_id"
    t.integer  "interval"
    t.integer  "interval_unit"
    t.decimal  "count"
    t.datetime "created_at",                  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                  :null => false
  end
```

But if I open the pgAdmin tool and look at the tables and column names in there, it is still using the old column name of kip_id .

Is there any step I am missing?

Comment: What does it tell you after running `bundle exec rails db:migrate`? Also, what does opening your rails console by doing `rails c` and running `Key_performance_interval` do (I presume that's your model)?

Comment: @Charles : after running rake:migrate, it shows me nothing. Just goes to next line

Comment: Usually that means that the migration has successfully run already. What does your rails console say? Also, I would restart postgres and restart rails.

Comment: what is the source of truth for Rails that is getting column name from? is it its Schema.rb file?  I now want to change key_performance_interval_id column name in the code above actually to key_performance_indicator_id

Comment: @Charles: sorry I didn't quite understand what to do it console?

Comment: Well, if none of what I suggested works, change your db schema as required and then run `rake db:schema:load`. This will create the status quo database without running any migrations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24405/discussion-between-charles-and-user1899082)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since migrating the database gives no output, it seems that the migrations ran fine. Just restart pAdmin and the changes should be reflected there.

To also prepare your test database, run

```
$ rake db:test:prepare
```